# Is the subgroup of a non-abelian group is non-abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the following statement always true

> Subgroup of a non-abelian group is non-abelian

Comment: Pick nonabelian $G$. Pick $g \in G$. Examine the subgroup $\langle g \rangle$ generated by $g$. Report your findings.

Answer (score 3):

No, the center of a group is a subgroup which is always abelian.

Answer (score 2):

The trivial group $\{e_G\}$ is a subgroup of each group.